C# data within in-memory database persists in different test runs
I'm writing an integration test for my API. I've decided to go for an in-memory database however, I'm having some issues.
When I first ran the test, everything ran smoothly and I was returned a 200Ok result.
When I re-run the test, the test fails and I've realised it fixes itself when I change the email.
Since then, I've implemented a proper teardown method so it's destroyed at the end of the test however I'm still unsure as to why the data still exists even thought the WebApplicationFactory is created each time and I have services.RemoveAll(typeof(AppDbContext)); execute before it creates the in-memory database again?
Also, isn't the in-memory database supposed to only exist within memory? Why does the data still persist after the test finishes and I've closed visual studio, and shutdown my PC? Is there some caching mechanism involved?
Also, I'd like to specify that I used the Dipose() and Disposed properly but the problem still persisted.
Original code below:
    public class IntegrationTest
    {
        protected readonly HttpClient _testClient;
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _appFactory;

        protected IntegrationTest()
        {
            _appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
                .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                {
                    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.RemoveAll(typeof(AppDbContext));

                        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                        {
                            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"); 
                        });

                        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                        .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                        .BuildServiceProvider();


                        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                        using var scope = sp.CreateScope();

                        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                        var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
                        db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                    });
                });
            _testClient = _appFactory.CreateClient();
        }

        protected async Task AuthenticateAsync()
        {
            _testClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetBearerTokenAsync());
        }

        private async Task<string> GetBearerTokenAsync()
        {
            // Register user
            var registerResponse = await _testClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/register", new
            {
                email = "test@gmail.com",
                password = "Passw0rd."
            });
            registerResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

Changed value of email as that was causing the issue
Implemented proper teardown to destroy database at the end of the test

Does this answer your question? Access in memory dbcontext in integration test

If you are using some test framework like MSTest, it would be better to move the initialization logic from the class constructor to [TestInitialize] annotated method and introduce [TestCleanup] annotated method where you dispose _appFactory. This way, you will have a fresh instance of _appFactory for every test case.
